# How can I edit a mini-panels output?

Tags: 7, panels

I have a minipanel that out puts a price, based on the node, but without a currency symbol. I wanted to add a dollar sign so created a new .tpl file and added it as such:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $id; ?> <?php print $attributes; ?>>
  $<?php print render($content); ?>
</div>
```

However, the content renders a div as well, so on the front end I get:

```
$
<div class="entity-property entity-property-price">
49.99
</div>
```

Would anyone know where I can access this 'entity-property' div so I can drop in my '$' sign?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was yet another .tpl file, just for this element, I could copy from the moduel and place in my themes directory - component.tpl.php